# How to conclude whether the full text service is installed and/or used?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

```
SELECT FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

Above query returns 0

However, the below query returns 1 for all user databases. How to conclude whether the full text service is installed and/or used?

```
SELECT name,is_fulltext_enabled
FROM sys.databases
```

Answer (score 4):

The `FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')` is the important part. If it's not installed, you cannot use it.

It will let you create a `FULLTEXT CATALOG` and `STOPLIST`, but not the `INDEX`.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [ft_catalog] WITH ACCENT_SENSITIVITY = OFF
GO

CREATE FULLTEXT STOPLIST [ft_stoplist]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo];
GO

go
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test
(
    Id int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Test_Id PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
)

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].Test(
[sWord] LANGUAGE 'English')
KEY INDEX PK_Test_Id ON (Id, FILEGROUP [PRIMARY])
WITH (CHANGE_TRACKING = AUTO, STOPLIST = [ft_stoplist])
```

> Msg 7609, Level 17, State 5, Line 25
> Full-Text Search is not
> installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.

The [DATABASEPROPERTYEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/databasepropertyex-transact-sql) sheds more light on the matter (emphasis mine)

> IsFulltextEnabled - Note: The value of this property now has no
> effect. User databases **are always enabled** for full-text search. A
> future release of SQL Server will remove this property. **Do not use
> this property** in new development work, and modify applications that
> currently use this property as soon as possible.